# What is the best practice to provide a test account for Google SignIn in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-signin, google-play-console

I have an Android app that uses Google SignIn as a sign-in method.
In the Google Play Console, I'm supposed to provide a test account for Google to conduct app reviews. However, I'm facing an issue with that.

Even though I provide a Google account to test, as you can see in the below screenshot, there's an Identification Verification step that blocks Google reviewers to proceed with their job.

[image]

From my understanding, this step appears when Google suspects a sign-in. Although this test account is created/used in Japan, Google reviewers use it in other countries e.g. India (most of the time), the US, etc, that would be why this sign-in is considered as suspicious.

Then here's a question. What can I do about this situation? Just for your references, I already tried the following but nothing helped.

- Disable 2FA (i.e. No additional authentication is configured)
- Sign out from the test account in all of my devices (IIRC, with this approach, previously Google reviewers succeeded in sign-in without the Identification Verification step, but seems not this time)

Google reviewers or even their support team will never help me with this so it'd really be appreciated it if you know the workaround. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem with 2FA (phone number sign in). We provided steps to work around the registration which automatically logged them into a test account but they didn't follow the steps.
 Our only alternative seems to be to hard code an SMS code for the phone number provided but this seems so insecure, and they won't respond to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly:

1. Create a test Google account
2. Switch on 2-factor-authentication
3. Generate few 8-digit-one-time-use backup codes
4. include this test google account and codes in your Google Play Console Instruction for testers under App content -> App access -> Manage -> All or some functionality is restricted -> and provide credentials, generated codes and short instruction

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/v68sw8/protip_when_submitting_an_app_to_google_play_for/?rdt=44494

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, and I don't think I will, at least shortly, but I accept it as it looks promising. Thank you!